# Opened iPhone SE wrong - screen with lines and no video

Tags: iphone, hardware, screen, repair

I just yanked my phone screen a little when opening my SE. Now the display turns on but has lines and looks very broken. I am pretty sure it's the ribbon cables but I don't know where to get replacements and can't find any guides on the obvious sites like iFixit.

What I need to know is if it's definitely a problem with the ribbon cables. Where can I get parts and guides to fix it?

[image: broken iPhone display, blue and black lines, some dark patches]

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately you have damaged the LCD screen which wont allow you to see any visual output until replaced with a new/working screen.

I'm not sure about your location but iPhone repair shops/stalls are common place all over UK (hopefully USA too).

If you feel confident simply a replacement via  ebay or amazon following a step by step video guide like ' Jerry RIG ' on Youtube who has excellent tutorials.

Alternatively you can opt for a local vendor to fit a new screen, inadvertently checking everything else is ok and not damaged without you having to pay for a potentially unusable LCD screen!